How to make Search, Pagination, Services, Fixtures, JSON response, security and authentication in Symfony
I need help at my symfony project with the things listed up in the title.
I made a whole symfony project. But now as a beginner I don't know how to proceed.
I would be very grateful to a lot of help from the coding community. I get that maybe some one already has asked for this but i want to have the solutions at one place so I can talk to people on how to make it on my project.

Please focus on one problem per question, and share what you've tried to resolve it. Most of the requirements are widely documented

I think you'll find that the format for asking questions on SO is a lot more particular than other sites. Definitely check out How do I ask a good questions? to get a better understanding on what people here are looking for from questions.

Search
php bin/console make:Controller
SearchController:
#[Route('/search', name: 'app_search')]
public function index(Request $request, ProjektRepository $projektRepository, KontaktRepository $kontakteRepository, AufgabeRepository $aufgabenRepository): Response
{
    $query = $request->query->get('q');

    if ($query) {
        $projektResults = $projektRepository->search($query);
        $kontakteResults = $kontakteRepository->search($query);
        $aufgabenResults = $aufgabenRepository->search($query);

    }

    return $this->render('search/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'SearchController',
        'projektResults' => $projektResults,
        'kontakteResults' => $kontakteResults,
        'aufgabenResults' => $aufgabenResults,
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
}

BlockBody of the SearchView:
<div class="container">
    <h1>Search Results</h1>

    {% if projektResults is empty and kontakteResults is empty and aufgabenResults is empty %}
        <p>No results found for "{{ query }}".</p>
    {% else %}
        {% if not projektResults is empty %}
            <h2>Projekte</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for projekt in projektResults %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('app_projekt_show', {'id': projekt.id}) }}">
                            {{ projekt.Name }} [{{ projekt.Projektnummer }}]
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        {% if not kontakteResults is empty %}
            <h2>Kontakte</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for kontakt in kontakteResults %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('app_kontakt_show', {'id': kontakt.id}) }}">
                            {{ kontakt.Titel }} {{ kontakt.Nachname }} {{ kontakt.Vorname }} ({{ kontakt.Email }})
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        {% if not aufgabenResults is empty %}
            <h2>Aufgaben</h2>
            <ul>
                {% for aufgabe in aufgabenResults %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('app_aufgabe_show', {'id': aufgabe.id}) }}">
                            {{ aufgabe.Titel }}
                        </a>
                        <br>
                            {{ aufgabe.Beschreibung }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</div>

Repositories:
Choose the parameters you like:
public function search($query)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->where('a.Nachname LIKE :query')
        ->orWhere('a.Vorname LIKE :query')
        ->orWhere('a.Email LIKE :query')
        ->setParameter('query', '%'.$query.'%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}

Navbar in base.html.twig:
Add the Search bar to the nav bar for example:
<form class="d-flex" role="search" action="{{ path('app_search') }}">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>


You can read the documentation of symfony https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html and see how to implement the module you need. Also make your research by watching other questions and answers similar to your problem.

Is this an answer? You posted it as one. I take it you no longer need help from the community?

Pagination:
In the Controller Class:
#[Route('/', name: 'app_studenten_index', methods: ['GET'])]
public function index(StudentenRepository $studentenRepository): Response
{
    $page = $_GET['page'] ?? 1;
    $limit = $_ENV['PAGE_LIMIT'];
    // declare the PAGE_LIMIT in your .env file

    $students = $studentenRepository->findBy([], [], $limit, ($page-1) * $limit);

    $anzahlSeiten = ceil(count($studentenRepository->findAll()) / $limit);
    $anzahlSeiten = max($anzahlSeiten, 1);

    return $this->render('studenten/index.html.twig', [
        'studentens' => $students,
        'anzahlSeiten' => $anzahlSeiten,
        'currentPage' => $page,
    ]);
}

In the Twig File:
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if currentPage < 1 %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% elseif currentPage > 1 %}
            <li class="page-item">
                {% set prevPage = currentPage - 1 %}
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ prevPage }}" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if anzahlSeiten <= 1 %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">1</a></li>
        {% elseif anzahlSeiten > 1 %}
            {% for i in 1..anzahlSeiten %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if currentPage < 1 %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% elseif currentPage >= 1 and currentPage < anzahlSeiten %}
            <li class="page-item">
                {% set nextPage = currentPage + 1 %}
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ nextPage }}" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>
</nav>

Services
Services in Symfony
Sometimes you need to make a flash message to add your website a bit more professionality.
In your Controller:
#[Route('/new', name: 'app_kontakt_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, MessageGenerator $mg): Response
    {
     $message = $mg->getHappyMessage();
     $this->addFlash('erfolg', $message);
}

In the base.html.twig:
{% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        {% endblock %}

<div class="container">
        {% for label, messages in app.flashes(['erfolg', 'fehler']) %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="flash-{{ label }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

I also made a css:
.flash-erfolg {
    background-color: #d4edda; /* Hintergrundfarbe */
    color: #155724; /* Textfarbe */
    border-color: #c3e6cb;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.flash-fehler {
    background-color: #f8d7da; /* Hintergrundfarbe */
    color: #721c24; /* Textfarbe */
    border-color: #f5c6cb;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

Fixtures
class KurseFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager, ): void
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $kurs = new Kurse();
            $kurs->setName("Mathematik " . $i);
            $kurs->setKursbeschreibung("Angewandte Mathematik " . $i);
            $kurs->setKursdatum(date_create("2024-06-0" . $i));
            $kurs->setEctsPunkte(30);
            $kurs->setMaxTeilnehmer(100);


            $kurs->addStudenten($this->getReference("student " . $i));
            $kurs->setLehrer($this->getReference("lehrer " . $i));

            $manager->persist($kurs);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addReference("kurs " . $i, $kurs);
        }
    }

    public function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [
            UniversitaetFixtures::class,
            StudentenFixtures::class,
            LehrerFixtures::class
        ];
    }
}



class LehrerFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $lehrer = new Lehrer();
            //$lehrer->setKurs($this->getReference("kurs1"));
            $lehrer->setName("Hans Juergen " . $i);
            $lehrer->setBuero("A006" . $i);
            $lehrer->setTelefonnummer(123456788);
            $lehrer->setUniversitaet($this->getReference("uni " . $i));
            $lehrer->setEmail("hansi".$i."@gmail.com");

            $manager->persist($lehrer);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addReference("lehrer " . $i, $lehrer);
        }
    }
}


class StudentenFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $student = new Studenten();
            $student->setUniversitaet($this->getReference("uni " . $i));
            $student->setName("Lukas Bauer " . $i);
            $student->setAufnahmedatum(date_create(2022-02-02));
            $student->setMatrikelnummer("B0012" . $i);

            $manager->persist($student);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addReference("student " . $i, $student);
        }

    }
}


class UniversitaetFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $universitaet1 = new Universitaeten();
            $universitaet1->setName("uni " . $i);
            $universitaet1->setAdresse("Adresse " . $i);

            $manager->persist($universitaet1);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addReference("uni " . $i, $universitaet1);
        }

    }
}

To add all fixtures to the database you simply have to write in the console:
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append

Security and Authentication
First of all pay attention as you work through the points in symfony, to only use the things you need.
Make a User:
php bin/console make:user

To make the Authentication:
php bin/console make:auth

To make the registration:
php bin/console make:registration-form

Sometimes you need a bit more complicated registration:
class RegistrierungController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/reg', name: 'reg')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ValidatorInterface $validator): Response
    {
        $regform = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('username', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Mitarbeiter'])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Passwort wiederholen']
            ])
            ->add('registrieren', SubmitType::class)
            ->getForm();

        $regform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($regform->isSubmitted() && $regform->isValid()) {
            $eingabe = $regform->getData();
            $user = new User();

            $user->setUsername($eingabe['username']);
            $user->setPassword($passwordHasher->hashPassword($user, $eingabe['password']));

            $user->setRawPassword($eingabe['password']);

            $errors = $validator->validate($user);
            if (count($errors) > 0) {
                return $this->render('registrierung/anlegen.html.twig', [
                    'regform' => $regform->createView(),
                    'errors' => $errors
                ]);
            }

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_home'));
        }


        return $this->render('registrierung/register.html.twig', [
            'regform' => $regform->createView()
        ]);
    }
}

In the twig file you just need to add this:
{{ form(regform) }}

To check if the passwords of the users on your website still have secure passwords it is helpful to use:
NotCompromisedPassword in Symfony
JSONResponse
Here is an example for a JSONResponse in Symfony:
#[Route('/api', name: 'app_api')]
class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: '_index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return new Response("Hello world", Response::HTTP_OK, ['Content-type' => 'text/plain']);
    }

    #[Route('/reverse/{string?}', name: '_reverse')]
    public function reverse(?String $string): Response
    {
        if ($string === '' || $string === null) {
            return new Response("No string provided", Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, ['Content-type' => 'text/plain']);
        }
        return new Response(strrev($string), Response::HTTP_OK, ['Content-type' => 'text/plain']);
    }


    #[Route('/personen', name: '_personen')]
    public function personen(PersonRepository $pr): Response
    {
        $personen = $pr->findAll();

        return new JsonResponse($personen);
    }
}

In the Personen function there is a diffrent response type you can use it if you do this in your Person Entity
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PersonRepository::class)]
class Person implements \JsonSerializable
{

.
.
.

  public function jsonSerialize(): array
      {
          unset($this->eissorten);
          return get_object_vars($this);
      }
}


$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 1; - you should not use $_GET in Symfony

"Sometimes you need to make a flash message to add your website a bit more professionality." - how does a site look more professional through flash messages?

unset($this->eissorten); - why do you need to unset anything when serializing data? Also, why not use Symfony's Serializer for this?
